# Case insensitive checking if two strings matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to do a full text match on a string. Something like this:

If a user types in "beastie boys", I need to see if it matches the Capitalized/camel case (Beastie Boys) equivalent.

I have tried this:

```
str = "beastie boys"
str2 = "Beastie Boys"

puts str2.match(str)
```

Every time it comes back as nil.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "full text match"?

Comment: @dennis: **I need to see if it matches the camel case (Beastie Boys) equivalent.** You mentioned that you need to match the camel case tooo..

Comment: @SivaCharan - that is correct.. I jumped the gun a little early by claiming one's answer was correct... I will make my edits above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use casecmp:

```
str2.casecmp(str) == 0
```

Comment: Sweet!! This is exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = "Beasty Boys"
str.match /beasty\sboys/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming back as nil is the same as false.  When it matches it returns a MatchData object containing your string.

so you could do

```
if (str2.match(str))
  #do stuff
end
```

if you want to ignore case and match regardless

```
if (str2.downcase.match(str))
  #do stuff
end
```

and it will work